# How to import okhttp library in eclipse?

Tags: android, maven, jar

i imported okhttp library using external jar.but it says the class def found error.According to the documents, need to split two external library using [pom.xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okhttp%7Cokhttp%7C1.2.1%7Cjar)in eclipse project---> import --> maven-->install or deploy articraft to maven respiratory .and i don't know what is the articraft file.pls anyone help me?

Comment: have also add it in your workspace????

Comment: @PiyushGupta no i didn't add anything

Comment: No.my mean to say while you are importing project than there is option for "copy to workspace"...So have you enabled it?

Comment: so just enabled it...and get your solution.

Comment: @PiyushGupta i want to import external library using maven.i don't know what are u talking about. i didn't see any option copy to workspace

Answer (score 1):

Hi Divya I think that you are refereeing to [Missing com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util crash](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/282) that you can have with the latest 1.2.1 release of OkHttp.

To solve your issue please download [-with-dependences jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/1.2.1/okhttp-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) of that version.

Let me know if it solved your problem :)

Comment: can you please provide the whole exception?

Comment: Can you please also provide the code that is throwing that exception?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/215a4igg i don't know much about HTTP.just want to start to be a web developer.but this library irritating me lot

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception provided in the first pastebin I think you need to extend the Activity class since it seems like an Android project.

Secondly (based on your comments), you need to add the following dependency to the project's pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Square's page has good documentation - http://square.github.io/okhttp/